# How do I build a grpc Enum invariant from an int in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python

I have a grpc method used to query the internal state of some remote object on the server. This internal state includes an enum for the status, which I have replicated in the expected gRPC response message like this:

```
rpc QueryState (QueryRequest) returns (QueryResponse) {}

enum Status {
  STATUS_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
  STATUS_ONLINE = 1;
  STATUS_OFFLINE = 2;
}

message QueryRequest {}

message QueryResponse {
  STATUS status = 1;
}
```

The problem I have is that in the server-side implementation of `QueryState` is that I don't know how to properly build the `QueryResponse` object. This is because the actual value of the `status` field in the internal state object is an int (EnumInt, actually) which I then need to translate to the corresponding gRPC Enum invariant and I don't know how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

The gRPC client|server should share protobuf schemas so there is no discrepancy between the messages that the client and server exchange.

Protobuf `enum` are Python ints so these can be readily convert to other Python types.

If you're using Python's `Enum` class, `Enum` values can be convert to int using `value` and created from int.

```py
import foo_pb2

resp = foo_pb2.QueryResponse()

# Online
resp.status = foo_pb2.STATUS_ONLINE
print(resp)
print(type(resp.status))

from enum import Enum

class Status(Enum):
    UNSPECIFIED = 0
    ONLINE = 1
    OFFLINE = 2

# Offline (through Enum)
resp.status = Status.OFFLINE.value
print(resp)
print(type(resp.status))

# Create Enum from foo_pb2.Status
print(Status(resp.status))
```